# Slow fetching of records in dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using the following statement to fetch the results of query in dataset

```
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds = OdbcHelper.ExecuteDataset(Connection.ODBCConnection(), CommandType.StoredProcedure, "{ CALL Search_EQ_SP(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}", p);
```

all over my application.

I have two stored procedures Search_EQ_SP and Search_NF_SP. Both return nearly 90000 records. Both take less than 25 seconds to execute when checked in SQL Server. But when it comes to fetching data in dataset in C# Search_NF_SP takes 30-35 secs which is considerable but Search_EQ_SP takes 3 mins and above.

I still can't figure out if Search_EQ_SP is taking secs in SQL Server to execute then why it is taking so long to load data in dataset. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This is very common issue when You're using ExecuteDataSet. This issue generally may occur due to network bandwidth. Better monitor it for a while using [Microsoft Network Monitor](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865). First analyze the network using this utility, you could find some variation. Welcome to Your comment.

Another way to achieve the same is use DataReader. It could be the better option than DataSet for Large data. Read this article [DataSet vs. DataReader](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/420217/DataSet-vs-DataReader)
Hope this may help

Comment: But why it doesnt gets slow with  Search_NF_SP then?

Comment: Is there any other solution to fetch data faster?

Comment: If both the stored procedures are the same then You must share the exact code which is calling them. Because there must be some problem with it

Comment: Both procedures are not same.But both are fetching same number of records(above 80000). Code to call the procedures is the same (as given above).Execution time of both sps is less than 25 secs in sql server

Comment: From same I meant costing same Database server resource. Anyways I've edited the answer. DataReader is better approach when You're 
Developing Web application, dealing with Large data and  Returning multiple tables

Comment: If it is possible could you please share your code so that I could analyse it? 
Beside everything performance issue could be caused by 
de-normalized data in the database
slow network layer
or slow database server

Please make sure everything stated above is cross checked.